# multiple ipv6 from range on one machine

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6

I have a debian server and a pool of ipv6 addresses with `64` mask.
I want to split all ips between multiple servers, but configure it through masks, without adding 4 million ips to `/etc/network/interfaces`.
How to configure Linux machine, to be able to use ip from the given range?
For example, if i have `1111:20c:234c:e562::/71`, i want to be able to use all ips from this range. I mean, i can ping google.com with that command
`ping -I 1111:020c:234c:e562:0000:0000:0000:0000 google.com`
`ping -I 1111:020c:234c:e562:03ff:ffff:ffff:ffff google.com`

Comment: Subnets are divided into ranges, typically /64 for IPv6, but interfaces are only assigned at most a couple of addresses. It is impractical to assign 4 million addresses to an interface, let alone 2^57 (10^39) addresses.

Comment: @JohanMyréen
I have around 40 servers. Anyway, maybe it's possible to split only by thousands?

Comment: I have you have 40 servers, let your main gateway announce the /64 prefix, and they will configure their network interfaces accordingly (with a single IPv6 address, using the MAC address). Then you set up proper DNS, and use those particular address. Or use DHCPv6 with 40 static addresses. You **never** configure the complete range (just because you "got it"). If you want to do load balancing, do it with a single IPv6 address, on a device in front of your servers. If you really have to, you can also do load balancing with an IPv6 range.

Comment: @dirkt
I need this ip's on my machine, to be able to use as outgoing ips when i will perform some requests from it. 
TLDR, i want to use different ip from my pool each time(or random from available) for each request

Comment: If you are using IPv6 in the usual way, you don't have to do that. If you want to use it in a funny way, explain what you are doing, and why you need it. If you need to fake a source address, there are ways to do that. If you temporarily need an IPv6 address as source, just assign it to the interface as long as you need it.

Comment: @dirkt
Read pls TLDR above)

Comment: So `addr='1111:020c:234c:e562:0000:0000:0000:0000' ; ip addr add $ADDR dev eth0 ; ping -I $ADDR -c10 google.com ; ip addr del $ADDR`, rinse and repeat with other addresses. You add each address as long as you need it.

Comment: I recommend you read https://serverfault.com/a/591435/315951 (and its comments) for a thorough discussion of the issue.